# Movie: hero can control movement of people or things by sticking a paper on his forehead

Tags: story-identification, movie

Long ago there was this movie, set in Africa I guess, where the hero would control another thing (human or not) by sticking a paper or something similar to it on his forehead to control his movement. I think it was a comedy and the way he controlled that was hilarious.

Comment: Sounds a bit like a *jiangshi* (https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/ChineseVampire) and the prayer slip used to control them.

Comment: When was "long ago?"  Long enough ago for the movie to be black & white?  Why do you think it was set in Africa?

Comment: I think it was definitely in the 90's and if I remember the plot was set among lot of black tribes.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think there's a decent chance that you're referring to *[Crazy Safari](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crazy_Safari)*, which is sometimes billed as *The Gods Must Be Crazy 3* despite it being made by a different studio as a knock-off.

> An ancient but still fleshy Chinese corpse is on auction in England. A young businessman (Sam Christopher Chow) purchases the corpse. The corpse is revealed to be the body of his third great-grandfather and he intends to give it a proper burial in Hong Kong. To keep it from becoming an irrepressible vampire, the descendant hires a good-natured Taoist priest (Lam Ching Ying) to maintain control of the cadaver using a yellow talisman. The young descendant and the Taoist priest decide that the best way to get the valued ancestor home is via a direct flight to Hong Kong on a private jet.
>
> During the flight, the plane malfunctions and an altercation breaks out between the ruthless pilot and the two passengers. Luckily, they outsmart the pilot and descend from the troublesome plane by using parachutes. The corpse and the two end up separated during the chaos, and they land in Africa.
>
> The corpse lands in front of Xixo (N!xau), where he and his tribe are being confronted by a rival clan led by two greedy Caucasians. The corpse's presence scares away the villains. Xixo somehow learns to control the corpse and he takes it to his tribe. Soon he and his family think of it as a gift from God, as it aids them in various matters, such as bringing down fruit from towering trees.

### Movie scene

Found on the TV Tropes entry for [Chinese Vampire](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/ChineseVampire), which I was cued to by the control slip of paper on the forehead.